# Sync_gateway couchbase requireRole

Tags: couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a problem with the roles of `Sync_gateway`.
My `sync_function` throws an `missing role` error at `requireRole("adminSync");`.

I'm accessing with user admin1 that is configured as it follows:

```
  "name": "admin1",
  "all_channels": {},
  "passwordhash_bcrypt": "**************",
  "explicit_roles": {
    "adminSync": 1
  },
  "rolesSince": {
    "adminSync": 1
  }
```

Also I have the role configured as:

```
{
  "name": "adminSync",
  "admin_channels": {
    "CH_HORAS": 1,
    "CH_PERSONAS": 1,
    "CH_PROYECTOS": 1
  },
  "all_channels": {
    "CH_HORAS": 1,
    "CH_PERSONAS": 1,
    "CH_PROYECTOS": 1
  }
}
```

Any idea of this error??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re,
I found out what was wrong,

The variable **realUserCtx.roles** is a map, so according to the **requireRole(..)** which needs to compare two arrays, it always return false.

So I needed to change the source code of src/channels/sync_runner.go to convert this map into an array before the comparison.

```
function mapToArray(mapObject){
        var _array = [];
        if(mapObject){
            for (var property in mapObject) {
                _array.push(property);
            }
        }
        return _array;
    }
```

then..

```
function requireRole(roles) {
    ...
    if (!anyInArray(mapToArray(realUserCtx.roles), roles))
    }
```

If you need more explanations you can contact me in private message.
Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on the same problem. I looked into sync_gateway source code *src/channels/sync_runner.go* and found requireRole definition, which is :

```
function requireRole(roles) {
            if (!shouldValidate) return;
            roles = makeArray(roles);
            if (!anyInArray(realUserCtx.roles, roles))
                throw({forbidden: "missing role"});
    }
```

Nevertheless, I tried to add this part of code in my sync function :

```
console.log(Array.isArray(realUserCtx.roles));
```

..and it returned false.
 **realUserCtx.roles** is not an array, but a function and I don't know what is inside this function body.

I hope it can help find the solution.